# ag-grid custom filter options for date filter in angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Currently i'm using below way to assign new options to assigned date column field. But it's not getting displayed in grid.

```
let dateValues = ["equals", "inRange","quarter1","quarter2","quarter3","quarter4"];

{
    headerName: "Assigned Date",
    field: "assignedDate",              
    filter: "date",
    filterParams: {apply: true, newRowsAction: 'keep'},
    sort: 'desc',
    filterOptions: this.dateValues
 }
```

And looking for some pointers how can i set predefined date values for quater1,quater2,quater3 & quarter4 when use selects that option in drop down filter. I have gone through the ag-grid filters section, i don't find any option to customize this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the way to do it as you have done. Instead use it like this:

```
{
    headerName: "Assigned Date",
    field: "assignedDate",              
    filter: "date",
    filterParams: {apply: true, newRowsAction: 'keep'},
    sort: 'desc',
    filter: DropDownFilter
 }

function DropDownFilter() {
}

DropDownFilter.prototype.init = function (params) {
    this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
    this.filterText = null;
    this.setupGui(params);
};

// not called by ag-Grid, just for us to help setup
DropDownFilter.prototype.setupGui = function (params) {
    this.gui = document.createElement('div');
    this.gui.innerHTML =
        '<select><option value="equals">equals</option><option value="inRange">inRange</option></select>';

    this.eFilterText = this.gui.querySelector('#filterText');
    this.eFilterText.addEventListener("changed", listener); 
    var that = this;
    function listener(event) {
        that.filterText = event.target.value;
        params.filterChangedCallback();
    }
};

DropDownFilter.prototype.getGui = function () {
    return this.gui;
};
DropDownFilter.prototype.isFilterActive = function () {
    return this.filterText !== null && this.filterText !== undefined && this.filterText !== '';
};

DropDownFilter.prototype.getModel = function() {
    var model = {value: this.filterText.value};
    return model;
};

DropDownFilter.prototype.doesFilterPass = function (params) {
    return params.data.value === this.filterText.value;
}
DropDownFilter.prototype.setModel = function(model) {
    this.eFilterText.value = model.value;
};
```

Reference: [agGrid Filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom filter component that shows your options in a drop down. The built in date filter can show the 'filterOptions' that you provide in the column definition but will not perform the search that you expect (if a date is in a particular quarter). See the [custom Angular filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-filter/) example on ag-grid site.